Condicional simple/subjuntivo presente/subjuntivo imperfecto?
Estoy traduciendo algo para una amiga mía, y me topé con esta oración. ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de escribir lo siguiente? ¿Si varías están bien escritas, existe alguna diferencia en el significado de ellas?:

Necesito saber si viste algo que nos podría ayudar
Necesito saber si viste algo que nos pudiera ayudar
Necesito saber si viste algo que nos pueda ayudar

La prótasis describe algo que ocurrió en el pasado (viste), mas no me queda claro que lo mismo sea cierto de la subordinada relativa.

Necessitaba saber si viste algo que nos pudiera ayudar.

Podemos alargar un poquito tu ejemplo para ver mejor lo que pasa:

Necesito saber si viste algo que, en caso de que lo hayas visto,...

Es decir: tenemos dudas sobre si la prótasis es cierta. En estos casos hipotéticos, necesitamos el subjuntivo.
Tus dos últimas opciones son correctas y tienen diferencias de matiz. La segunda opción (pretérito imperfecto) indica más incertidumbre que la tercera (presente). Si dices:

Necesito saber si viste algo que nos pudiera ayudar

estás indicando que tienes menos esperanzas de que aquello que la otra persona haya visto pueda ser de ayuda que si dices:

Necesito saber si viste algo que nos pueda ayudar


Bien ahí con la última observación. Tal cual, no hay una correlación perfecta entre las supuestas denominaciones teóricas de tiempos verbales y los tiempos a los que (en la práctica) realmente hace referencia el verbo. En este sentido, es posible encontrar situaciones en donde la conjugación caiga bajo la etiqueta de ‘subjuntivo pretérito’ y que haga referencia al presente o incluso al futuro. Un ejemplo clásico es el de:

Me gustaría que vengas hoy a la fiesta.
Me gustaría que vinieras hoy a la fiesta.

Ambas conjugaciones refieren a lo mismo. Tus tres ejemplos son prácticamente lo mismo e intercambiables en la mayoría de los casos. En todo caso, si hay una diferencia es más que nada en cuanto al grado de probabilidad. Tu primer ejemplo es lo menos probable, y suena más natural decirlo como ‘algo que nos podría llegar a ayudar’. El segundo exige un poco más de certidumbre, y el tercero es bien directo, que por cierto, personalmente es lo que diría en la mayoría de las situaciones. Pero de nuevo, el análisis de ‘cuanta certidumbre se exige’ en cada uno de tus ejemplos es muy sutil, quizá metalingüístico, y ni siquiera sé si es algo que importe tanto para la comprensión o si lo tendría en cuenta como parte del corpus teórico de oraciones en subjuntuvo.
